# Ajax how to get variable in php file

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send var with input value from edit_pages.php to generate_pdf.php which is in iframe. How can I get input value in generate_pdf corectly? I need to reload page somehow on scucess with ajax to update iframe file?

edit_pages.php

```
<iframe id="miniBrowser" style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;" src="generate_pdf.php"></iframe>


<div class="worksheet">
    <div id="usrform">
      EDIT: <input class="usrname" type="text">
      <button id='zapisz'>zapisz</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$("#zapisz").on( 'click', function () {
   var usrname =  $('.usrname').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'generate_pdf.php',
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {usrnm:usrname},
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
alert(usrname);
})
</script>
```

in generate_pdf.php I'm trying to get ajax var, but I get undefined var.

```
$f1 = $_POST['usrnm'];
echo $f1;
```

Comment: That's a `POST` AJAX type for one.

Comment: I have tried with POST and GET, I think it has something to iframe. I get value corectly tested with alert. Just php in iframe doesn't get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on click get the username and load iframe src with the parameters. `fram.src`

**edit_pages.php**

```
<iframe id="miniBrowser" style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;" src="generate_pdf.php"></iframe>


<div class="worksheet">
    <div id="usrform">
      EDIT: <input class="usrname" id="username" type="text">
      <button id='zapisz'>zapisz</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Add jQuery Library if not added -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#zapisz").on( 'click', function () {

  var usrname =  $('#username').val();
  var frame = document.getElementById("miniBrowser");
  frame.src = "generate_pdf.php?usrnm="+usrname;

})
</script>
```

**generate_pdf.php**

```
$f1 = $_GET['usrnm'];
echo $f1;
```

received as GET

Comment: I'll test it soon and let you know :) Thanks

Comment: WOW Finally, thank you mate! Question is, why I couldn't make it with AJAX? I wasn't sending it to iframe, right?

Comment: @michal correct. you sent the username to generate...php. but it didnt loaded or refresh inside iframe

Answer (score 0):

In ajax  `type: "POST",` so in your php

```
$f1 = $_POST['usrnm'];
echo $f1;
```

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'generate_pdf.php',
            data: {usrnm:usrname},
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
```

if you want to pass get then

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'generate_pdf.php?usrnm='+usrname,
               success: function(data) {
                }
            });
```

Also you have forgot add name to input

usrname

```
<input class="usrname" type="text" name="usrname">
```

Comment: I should use get in generate_pdf.php file? Sorry I'm not really sure whre should I use GET

Comment: GET data are passing using url and POST are hidden.you can just change get to post in ur php that enough.since you are not retruning json so you can remove that from ajax

Comment: @iCoders If you use the GET method, then in PHP you have to use either the $_GET or $_REQUEST globals to retrieve the data.  $_POST will not have the data in a GET request.

Comment: <input class="usrname" type="text" name="usrname">

Comment: iCoders added that (I had it before), usrnm is valid in edit_pages.php, tested with alert. There is something with php file, it is in iframe so maybe I should reload it? I don't know...